# bgp hold timer error

Tags: cisco-nx-os

i have a cisco nexus 3064pq-10gx and i have a bgp session with my upstream and there is not a full table and i will see the following error 2-3 times a day in my switch log :

```
%BGP-5-ADJCHANGE:  bgp- [17873] (default) neighbor 172.x.x.33 Down - sent:  holdtimer expired error
```

i have check physical link and swap them with new ones and also i have contact my upstream and check MTU on both side was 1500 and i do not find any other useful information to debug this, seems everything is working fine,
any idea on this?
thanks,

Comment: Full BGP table on Nexus 3000?

Comment: no we do not have full bgp table,i correct that part, my mean was there is no full table

Comment: What NX-OS version ?  could be a bug CSCvj89823

Comment: Software
  BIOS: version 4.5.0
  NXOS: version 7.0(3)I7(8)
  BIOS compile time:  11/09/2017
  NXOS image file is: bootflash:///nxos.7.0.3.I7.8.bin
  NXOS compile time:  3/3/2020 20:00:00 [03/04/2020 08:19:49]

Comment: it seems that bug is available in 7.0(3)I7(3) but i am using 7.0(3)I7(8) which is newer, does not it? also i have 2x 10g LACP uplink from my upstream, also as another note when i face this issue all ports are up and they are up for more than 3-4weeks both physical ports and port-channel

Comment: If you have a Smartnet contract, I would call TAC.  It sounds very suspiciously like that bug.  There are many newer versions to upgrade to.

Comment: its also strange because i have 7x bgp peer and left of them are up and working without any issue, and unfortuently our smartnet contract finished some days ago.

Comment: "_unfortuently our smartnet contract finished some days ago._" You really want to get a new SmartNet contract. We cannot help you fix a bug.

Comment: Are the timers on the peer set to a non-default value?  If so, what?

Comment: Are you positive the IP MTU is 1500? Is your BGP running PMTUD?